# What's the difference between X-ray crystallography and X-ray spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

From my understanding, further evidence for the structures of molecules can be obtained from single crystal X-ray crystallography which involved irradiating a crystal with X-rays and looking at the positions and intensities of the diffracted beams. It gives a 3D picture of the molecule with bond lengths and angles. But does X-ray spectroscopy exist and if so how is it different?

Comment: Do a search for “XRF” or “x-ray fluorescence spectroscopy”. Commercial instruments are available.

Comment: thanks @EdV will do

Comment: The use of incident x-rays, electrons, or other charged particles (primarily protons or alphas in my experience) to induce atoms to emit characteristic x-rays is quite common in materials characterization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In x-ray crystallography, the x-ray spectrum is known. The objective is to determine the crystal structure.

A crystal spectrometer for x-rays inverts this: a crystal whose structure is known is used to determine the spectrum. But there are also grating spectrometers for x-rays, and nondispersive spectrometers that measure the energy each photon deposits in a detector rather than dispersing the radiation by wavelength.